# Importing into SQL Server directly from Zipped File

Tags: sql-server, import

I have a simple 4 column text file with billions of rows (say Huge_file.txt ). Now the Huge_File.txt after compressing is around 1 TB in zipped format with around 11 % compression rate ( after unzipping the size will balloon upto 10 TB or so.)

Is there a way to load Huge_File.txt without unzipping?(Space issues on server.) Like something similar to how Redshift imports a zipped file from S3 without unzipping it.

P.S. I am using SQL Server 
Version : Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64) 
    Oct 28 2016 18:17:30 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3  (Build 14393: )

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not, but this is only the first of many speed bumps you are going to run into. If 10TB is an issue, then you may not be able to solve the others... like how are you going to import that much data? How long do you except it to take and how long is too long? This could take hours... or longer depending on your setup. Also, how large will the mdf and ndf files be after? Is space for those an issue? You have the $$ to afford SQL Server EE but not and extra 10TB of space? Odd. That's like $14K per core.

Comment: The database is on another server which has been storage optimized and we have an application server which is process optimized. So we run ssis or bulk import on the application server but the data is stored on the Database server. So the mdf , ndf and ldf size wont be an issue. The time required would not be an issue since it is a one time thing and the server configuration are pretty good except for storage. I am just trying to figure out if i can do this with the current storage limitations else i can ask for a higher storage capability. Hope this helps in understanding the requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server will not read from a "Compressed Folder" (aka a ZIP file), so unless you find some third-party extension that could do this for you, your only options other than the 10TB file would be (1) Manually segment the expanded file, and import in multiple batches, or (2) add another drive. Technically, (3) unzip to a compressed drive - might be a valid solution, but drive compression is usually pretty lousy overall compression, so it wouldn't be as small as the ZIP file.

Comment: Well since you are using SSIS I'd add the step to unzip there. It's the path of least resistance but echoing what i said and @LaughingVergil you can't do it out of the box.

Comment: Got it. Just wanted to see if there was something that i was missing. Thanks for the help, @scsimon and LaughinVergil